# QThread moveToThread doesn't work

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I've a main thread for the GUI, in which is run the `MainWindow` object,
in its constructor I create a new worker object and a `QThread` object and the i move the worker to the thread, the problem is that when printing their ids  they are the same:

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    std::cout<<"MAIN_ID "<< QThread::currentThreadId()<<std::endl;
    QThread *t_pc = new QThread;
    worker *pc_w;
    pc_w = new pc_worker();
    pc_w->moveToThread(t_pc);
    t_pc->start();
    pc_w->initialize();
    // ...
}
```

**worker.cpp**

```
worker::worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {

}

void worker::initialize() {
    std::cout << "INITIALIZE " << QThread::currentThreadId() << std::endl;
}
```

I get:

```
MAIN_ID 0x7f4009ccb780
INITIALIZE 0x7f4009ccb780
```

What's wrong?

Comment: But then,when the worker class is called through connect SLOT/SIGNAL the printed IDs are different

Comment: When you call a function directly, it will run in the thread you call it from.

Comment: Define initialize() as a slot and emit a signal from MainWindow. Connect them like this: connect(this, SIGNAL(signal_initialize()), pc_w, SLOT(initialize()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

Answer (score 4):

Answer: `moveToThread` **does** work, just not in the way you expected.

Looks like after calling `pc_w->moveToThread(t_pc)` you expected all member functions of `pc_w` to be called in `t_pc` now. However, that is not what `moveToThread()` does.

The purpose of `moveToThread()` is to change `QObject` "thread affinity" or in other words thread where an object lives. **But** on the basic level everything it gives you is just the guarantee that all the object`s slots connected to any signal via `Qt::QueuedConnection` will be *invoked* (run) in that particular thread.

Member functions still run in the thread you invoke them from. In your case, you call `initialize()` from the GUI thread, so `QThread::currentThreadId()` gives you the *id* of that thread.

I really recommend to read official doc on [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) and [this article](http://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects) on thread event loops.

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker;

// Uses Qt::AutoConnection (default)
// which will be transalted into Qt::QueuedConnection
QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::initialize);

std::cout<<"MAIN_ID "<< QThread::currentThreadId()<<std::endl;

worker->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

Output:

```
MAIN_ID 0000000000003E5C
INITIALIZE 0000000000003DAC
```

---

The solution **trivelt** proposed artificially puts "call `initialize()`" event into the thread event loop reaching the same effect. However, it does not perform any compile-time checks ("initialize" is specified as a string).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`invokeMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) instead of diretly calling `pc_w->initialize()`, e.g.:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(pc_w, "initialize", Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Your `initialize()` method should be SLOT or SIGNAL in this case.